# Form with Angular.js form and Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webforms

I'm trying to submit a form with Angular. I need that Node makes the login and redirect to the main web.

My problem is, that after I submit the form, I send the info to Node but Node has a failureRedirect and I'm in the same web. I know that the login code works because I implemented it without Angular and works.

```
modulo.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log' , function($scope, $http, $log){
$scope.message = 'Hello World!';

$scope.formVisibility = false;

$scope.ShowForm = function(){
    $scope.formVisibility = true;
};

$scope.User = {};
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url : "/login",
    data : $scope.User
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){

}); }]);
```

I was reading about the $http service and the config var, but I don't know how to make the call.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Is it in the browser or in node? What does your `/login` route look like?

Comment: In the browser, I don't get a successRedirect from Node